# I want to show div on scroll getting TypeError: $ is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a simple jQuery script in a WordPress plugin that is using a jQuery wrapper like this:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $window.scroll(function () {
       300 < $(this).scrollTop() ? $(".ftr_cta_blk").fadeIn() : $(".ftr_cta_blk").fadeOut()
     })

   });
 </script>
```

I am getting an Error TypeError: $ is not a function.

My  jQuery version is v1.12.4

Comment: Hi, Did you check if you are calling this script before or after including the jQuery library?

Comment: also note that you have an error with the line `$window.scroll(function` it should be like this: `$(window).scroll(function`

Comment: I have tried this  $(window).scroll(function() { same error

Comment: Okay this might be due to some conflicting with the $ sign, try replacing the $ in this script to the keyword **jQuery**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this solution, it will work on all latest JQuery

```
// JavaScript Document
<script type = "text/javascript">
   jQuery(function ($) {
    var _document, _window, _html, _body;
    _document = $(document);
    _window = $(window);
    _html = $('html');
    _body = $('body');

    _window.on('scroll', function () {
      if (_window.scrollTop() >= 300) {
        $(".ftr_cta_blk").fadeIn();
      } else {
        $(".ftr_cta_blk").fadeOut();
      }
    });
  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: Working 100% with both Old and New JQuery

Answer (score 4):

If nothing has worked yet try the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $(window).scroll(function () {
       (300 < $(this).scrollTop()) ? $(".ftr_cta_blk").fadeIn() : $(".ftr_cta_blk").fadeOut()
     })

   });
 </script>
```

Comment: @AnitaMandal don't forget to remove the other previous call of the jQuercy library just not to load jQuercy twice

Comment: If I am using jquery-latest.min.js which is  jQuery v1.11.1 my other sliders not working. Is there any solution to work above jQuery v1.2 versions ?

Comment: what do you mean your other sliders won't work, slider like <input type="range"> ? or something else?

Comment: On my WordPress I have Revolution slider which is working v1.12.4 but when I am adding above script which has jQuery v1.11.1 then the home page slider not working,

Comment: @AnitaMandal sorry I don't know how to fix this, hope someone help you

Answer (score 1):

try the following, Previous answer may overload your site

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
       (300 < $(this).scrollTop()) ? jQuery(".ftr_cta_blk").fadeIn() : jQuery(".ftr_cta_blk").fadeOut()
     })

   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Not working, its working only below jQuery v1.11.1.